# os.system() uses inputfile as args and raises unrecognized arguments error

Tags: command-line-arguments

I use MOPAC program in commandline "`mopac temp.dat`" - it works perfectly resulting in a new temp.arc file
Then I try `os.system("mopac temp.dat")` in my python script, it results in 2 (which stands for not successfull):

```
usage: mopac [-h] [-o OUT]
mopac: error: unrecognized arguments: temp.dat
```

Apperently, it uses temp/temp.dat as an argument that is absent in the argument list?

I've tried:

```
subprocess.run(["mopac"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, input="temp.dat")
```

It gives 1 (like in case of simple `os.system(mopac)`)
and:

```
subprocess.run(["mopac"], input="temp.dat")
```

And in the second case: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Did you check the documentation of `subprocess.run`? It explains why your code doesn’t work and how to fix it.

Comment: I've tried the most obvious variant subprocess.run(["mopac", "temp.dat"]), but it didn't work either.. now it works. Surprisingly, now os.system("mopac temp.dat") works as well. And I don't know why it was not working yesterday... Thanks anyway.